# Cannot activate Logical Volume which was managed by Pacemaker

Tags: linux, storage, lvm, iscsi, pacemaker

I have two CentOS 7 servers that clustered with Corosync and Pacemaker to work in Active/Passive way. The whole idea was to move the mount point in case of a problem emerges in the active node. My client wanted to do security hardening and after that, they rebooted the servers. After reboot, I wasn't able to start the cluster again.

So I destroyed the cluster and wanted to configure all over again. But the File System resource wasn't able to start for some reason. When we have checked our logs, we saw that `fusvg that is some volume group does not close correctly` error.

I figured this should be a problem with lvm partition. Logical volume shows Not Active. I tried `lvchange -a y fusvg` command to activate it but didn't work.

My Logical Volume device file is not present at `/dev/fusvg/fuslv` as `lvdisplay` output shows.

Here is `lvdisplay` output:

```
[root@machine-name ~]# lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/fusvg/fuslv
  LV Name                fuslv
  VG Name                fusvg
  LV UUID                rL2svQ-kxnJ-GdD8-2aKX-Omcv-eywn-Q5rtRG
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time machine-name, 2018-06-22 13:34:13 +0300
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                <30.00 TiB
  Current LE             7864318
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
```

Here is `vgdisplay` output:

```
[root@machine name ~]# vgdisplay 
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               fusvg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  21
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <30.00 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              7864318
  Alloc PE / Size       7864318 / <30.00 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               CMG3yi-qHSO-3qMP-CF1h-nG9Y-Uh34-KlWwiI
```

Here is `lsblk` output:

```
NAME                                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                                       8:0    0 446.6G  0 disk  
├─sda1                                    8:1    0     1G  0 part  /boot
├─sda2                                    8:2    0 317.6G  0 part  /
└─sda3                                    8:3    0   128G  0 part  [SWAP]
sdb                                       8:16   0    30T  0 disk  
└─36000d31003f63c000000000000000003     253:1    0    30T  0 mpath 
  └─36000d31003f63c000000000000000003p1 253:3    0    30T  0 part  
sdc                                       8:32   0     5G  0 disk  
└─36000d31003f63c000000000000000004     253:0    0     5G  0 mpath 
sdd                                       8:48   0    30T  0 disk  
└─36000d31003f63c000000000000000003     253:1    0    30T  0 mpath 
  └─36000d31003f63c000000000000000003p1 253:3    0    30T  0 part  
sde                                       8:64   0     5G  0 disk  
└─36000d31003f63c000000000000000004     253:0    0     5G  0 mpath 
sdf                                       8:80   0    30T  0 disk  
└─36000d31003f63c000000000000000003     253:1    0    30T  0 mpath 
  └─36000d31003f63c000000000000000003p1 253:3    0    30T  0 part  
sdg                                       8:96   0     5G  0 disk  
└─36000d31003f63c000000000000000004     253:0    0     5G  0 mpath 
sdh                                       8:112  0    30T  0 disk  
└─36000d31003f63c000000000000000003     253:1    0    30T  0 mpath 
  └─36000d31003f63c000000000000000003p1 253:3    0    30T  0 part  
sdi                                       8:128  0     5G  0 disk  
└─36000d31003f63c000000000000000004     253:0    0     5G  0 mpath
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this today on a Dell HA setup. Not sure if this is specific to their implementation, or if it's standard everywhere, but [SuSE's KB "Getting errors while trying to activate a shared LVM volume group"](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019663) led me to add the shared volume group to the `volume_list` setting in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`. Once that was done, I could do an `lvchange` and start mounting the shared filesystem.

Comment: The problem I was facing was due to the storage device itself (I am not sure what was the problem and what they did to fix that though.). After the storage team fix their issue, I was able to use LVM partition and start my cluster from scratch.